# Updating multiple subdocuments in arrays all at once using Mongoose

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I am very new to Mongodb attempting to learn how to work with embedded documents that have complex subdocuments in arrays.  I have 2 schemas User and the Profiles the User can have and need to an existing profile to the new profile which modifies the existing profile. However, despite my searches I cannot find anything remotely similar to this update requirements, I am ab
le to update the top document but the arrays of subdocuments poses a challenge. The challenge is navigating and matching the right documents and updating them all at once. The problem is that the data varies for each subdocument in the array

```
    const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema(
    {
     
      user_id: { type: Number,  required: [true, 'You must provide an id'],unique:true},              
      url_link: { type: String, unique: true},
      user_name: { type: String, unique: true, required: [true, 'You must provide a 
      user name'] },
      profiles: [{ type: ProfileSchema}]
     }
   );



    const   ProfileSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        profile_id: { type: String, required: [true, 'You must provide your profile id'],unique: true },
        user_id: { type: Number,  required: [true, 'You must provide an user id'], unique:true },
        profile_type: { type: String,  unique: true }
    });
    
    module.exports = ProfileSchema;
```

module.exports = ProfileSchema;

//Existing User Profile

```
      {
        "user_id": 33455,
        "url_link": "https://media/profile-images/33455",
        "user_name": "Monserat Kamucho ",
        "profiles": [{
                "profile_id": "monserat_kamucho",
                "user_id": 33455,
                "profile_type": "twitter"
            },
            {
                "profile_id": "monserat_kamucho",
                "user_id": 33455,
                "profile_type": "instagram"
            },
            {
                "profile_id": "monserat_kamucho",
                "user_id": 33455,
                "profile_type": "tiktok"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Needs to be update for this user to

```
        {
        "user_id": 33455,
        "url_link": "https://media/profile-images/33455",
        "user_name": "monserat_kamuchoi",
        "profiles": [{
                "profile_id": "monserat_kamucho_twitter",
                "user_id": 33455,
                "profile_type": "twitter"
            },
            {
                "profile_id": "monserat_kamucho_instagram",  
                "user_id": 33455,
                "profile_type": "instagram"
            }
            
        ]
    }
```

Comment: What's your condition to update the array? To remove based on `profile_type` you can do [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qvvHlucjH52).

Comment: The update for twitter & instagram you can do with arrayFilters in single query: https://mongoplayground.net/p/pvsf0JwuXYZ   , so in general you need two queries , one for the $set and one for the $pull

Comment: Thank you for providing this solution, can the $pull be done in the same query?